# Eslint extension on vscode gives error "Parsing error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-react'"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, eslint

Hi i have a project that uses Eslint and i and my team members installed the vscode extension Eslint.

for some of us the extension works fine while for me and others we get the error "Parsing error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-react'"

We dont have @babel/preset-react or @babel/core installed as dev dependencies and we like to not install in locally into the project (installing those were recommended on the answers i found)

We tried to install them globally but it also didn’t work, I imagine there is problem with eslint maybe something that needed to be downloaded but we dont know.

I would like to be able to solve it without installing packages into to the project itself or changing the eslintrc file

structure of the project:

```
project
 - client folder
    - package.json (client)
    - eslintrc file
 - server folder
 - package.json (server)
 - server.js
```

our eslintrc file

```
{
  "extends": "airbnb",
  "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser",
  "root": true,
  "env": {
    "browser": true
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "requireConfigFile": false,
    "babelOptions": {
      "presets": ["@babel/preset-react"]
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "semi": ["error", "never"],
    "max-len": [2, 120, 2, { "ignoreComments": true }],
    "no-nested-ternary": 0,
    "no-confusing-arrow": 0,
    "arrow-parens": [2, "as-needed", { "requireForBlockBody": true }],
    "no-mixed-operators": 0,
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": 0,
    "react/no-this-in-sfc": 0
  }
}
```